# APACHE SOLR QUERY

Tags: solr

Solr is an already registered domain.
let's think. The name of the field is a field kept as “updatedAt” long type. I am from January 2020
When I say fetch the next data, what kind of query should be written to solr? http://example?query=
How should I fill in the part?

I need a query example to write to the Apache Solr service. a field kept of type ‘long’. When i say ‘I need data after January 2020’ What kind of query should I write? I don't need to LocalDateTime. I guess I should use timestamp. But I don't know how I can I write... For example: ?q=updatedAt:[ 1577836800000 TO *]

Comment: I'm having a hard time parsing your question - can you try to expand your question with a proper example? What is the field type of your `updatedAt` field? If you want to return any values for a date field after `2020-01-01`, you can use `?q=updatedAt:[2020-01-01 TO *]` as the query string.

Comment: My english is weak, im so sorry. I need a query example to write to the Apache Solr service. a field kept of type ‘long’. When i say ‘I need data after January 2020’ What kind of query should I write? I don't need to LocalDateTime. I guess I should use timestamp. But I don't know how I can I write...

 For example:  

?q=updatedAt:[ 1577836800000 TO *]

Comment: Use a datefield and the syntax I gave; no worry about your English skills - I'm just trying to understand what you're trying to solve. I'd do `updateAt:[2020-02-01 TO *]` in that case - if you're using timestamps you can do it was you've written, but using actual dates in a datefield can be helpful if you want to do range facets or use timezones with the `TZ` parameter later - it'll also be better formatted when returned from Solr.

Comment: Thank you so much. Don't I have to use timestamp when I say from January 2020? bcs https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/working-with-dates.html

Comment: I'm not sure what part of that page refers to having to use epoch timestamps instead of readable dates - both in your fields (when indexing/retrieving) and when querying; the examples for date ranges show that as long as you've indexed things as proper date fields, you can use syntax like `[2023 TO *]` to get everything in 2023 and later for example.

Comment: oh, got it. so how can i write? is that true? ---> http://example?q=updateAt:[2020-02-01 TO *]

Comment: Correct, you'll usually have something like `/solr/collectionname/select?q=updateAt:[20202-02-01 TO *]`, where `collectionname` is the name of your collection or core.